# Can I measure the quality of a literature review chapter of a thesis by whether its arguments are consistent or not?

Tags: literature-review

Can I measure the quality of literature review by analyzing the argument created in the literature review chapter of a masters thesis to see whether the arguments are consistent or inconsistent?

Comment: The title and the body of this question are completely different.

Comment: It would help answer your question if you gave more context. Specifically, what is your role (the master's student, advisor, committee member, unrelated reader, etc.)? What is your goal for the evaluation (approve the thesis, depend on the literature review for your own work, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

An inconsistent argument is bad, but an consistent argument alone is not enough for a good literature review. The primary purpose of a literature review is to give an overview of the state of the art in a specific field. A chapter that fails to adequately cover the field is a bad literature review, even if the argument is consistent.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how can I measure the arguments whether it a good argument or not, in case literature review of masters theses

Comment: @Rey This is not something you measure. It is something you evaluate based on your expertise and experience with the topic.

Comment: measure and evaluate is quite different (cultural reasons)

Comment: @Tobias  so can i evaluate the Arguments?

Comment: @ReySakti what stops you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an argument's logical consistency is useful, in and of itself, to determine the quality of a piece of written work. An argument is logically consistent if there are no logical contradictions. That is to say, all statements in the argument can be held as true at the same time. If it cannot, then the argument is logically contradictory. For example, the following statement is explicitly contradictory:

> "Carotid endarterectomy is both cost-effective and not cost-effective in the prevention of stroke in patients with carotid stenosis."

In this case, the author might not be asserting the contradiction, but has poorly summarised the conflicting evidence from research that shows that the cost-effectiveness of carotid endarterectomy is not established with certainty. This is a common enough technique in literature reviews in which the research gap is defined.

In some cases, arguments may be implicitly contradictory. Take, for example, that great line used to demonstrate borderline personality disorder:

> "I hate you. Please don't leave me."

Here, the idea plays on the meaning of "hate" as a strong emotion and the equally contrasting sense of "need". Once again, there is no logical consistency in this statement, but it is a valid statement nonetheless.

Finally, logical consistency is actually a low bar to surmount. An argument can be made logically consistent simply by asserting unrelated premises.

```
A. Some rats are white.
B. All viruses are tiny.
= = = = = = = = = = = = = 
C. Therefore, carotid endarterectomy is suitable for carotid stenosis.
```

This is a logically consistent syllogism, but you will agree that this is a fine example of invalid reasoning.